# How to open a new conversation in Microsoft Teams via deep link URI?

Tags: uri, microsoft-teams

I know there is a URI scheme that can open Microsoft Teams, such as `msteams://MY_PATH`.

Now, how can I use this URI scheme to open a new conversation with a specific contact, given the contact email?

Bonus question: is there any way I can also attach a message to the newly created conversation? *I don't need this message to be sent, but only to fill the message field in the newly created conversation.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to do this using Deep Links. In particular see [Deep linking to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat). In particular, it says:

> You can create deep links to private chats between users by specifying the set of participants. If a chat doesn't exist with the specified participants, the link will navigate the user to an empty new chat.

I don't think you can send an attachment directly, as the conversation doesn't *actually* exist until the first message is posted (per the link: "New chats will be created in draft state until the user sends the first message"). Perhaps there is an alternative though - you can pre-create the first message in a draft state (see the optional "message" parameter) and you could insert a link to a file stored in the Team's SharePoint document store / OneDrive / other.

Example URL:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>,...&topicName=<chat name>&message=<precanned text>
```

Comment: I need the message to be a draft and not be sent, so this is really good news. I edited my question to clarify this point. Could you add an example URI?

Comment: @DanieleMolinari-  Here is the sample URL- `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>,...&topicName=<chat name>&message=<precanned text>`

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT, you beat me to it. Daniele, note that this takes in <user> in the form of email (users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com). Technically, it's actually UPN, but that's practically email addresses in most cases.

Comment: Sounds like your questions is pretty much answered now?

Comment: Edited your answer to add URL and selected as solution.